# ARM. Inject .cantunwind directive to C funtion

Tags: c, gcc, android-ndk, arm, clang

There is some C code that is compiled with Android NDK Clang toolchain for ARM architecture. For debugging purposes we may collect backtraces with `_Unwind_Backtrace()`, but often such backtraces have a lot of frames under my JNI methods. They are some internals for ART and compiled Java bytecode.

I would like to stop unwinder on my JNI method to avoid drilling down to JVM frames. If it would be assembly I'd probably put [`.cantunwind`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Directives.html) on my functions. But it is C so is there any way to force this directive in C for arbitrary function?

Comment: Wny not use inline assembler with just `asm(".cantunwind\n");`?  You can make it a macro for easy removal.

Comment: @artlessnoise smart idea, but it doesn't work unfortunately. This directive conflicts with personality rountine record and exception table that compiler generates. Assembler fails with `/tmp/native-lib-b2b1d5.s:355: Error: duplicate .personality directive
/tmp/native-lib-b2b1d5.s:356: Error: attempt to recreate an unwind entry`